# react useRef typescript child forwardedRef type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm forwarding a ref to Child component as per the react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html.

```
const userRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);

interface IWrappedComponent {
  ref?: RefObject<TextInput>;
}

const WrappedComponent = React.forwardRef((props: IWrappedComponent, ref) => {
  return <LogProps {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />;
});

interface ILogProps {
  innerRef?: RefObject<TextInput>;
}
```

However I'm getting a type error for forwardedRef. I'm using `RefObject<TextInput>` for type, but am getting the following:

```
Type 'ForwardedRef<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<TextInput>'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<TextInput>'.
```

Comment: Can you add your type definition as well here?

Comment: ive updated updated the types

Comment: I have the same problem.... did you end up finding a solution?